# Set a tab page on lload event of a form

Tags: c#

i have a form with many tabs on it. I want to set a specific tab page to show on load of the form everytime i load the form

I used TabPageControl1.SelectedTab=MyTabPage;
but the value of selectedtab is null. 
It is throwing an exception that reference not set to an object.

```
private void PreferencesForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cbxCustomDataType.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        this.cbxCustomDataType.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cbxCustomDataType_DrawItem);

        this.cbxColumnDataType.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        this.cbxColumnDataType.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cbxColumnDataType_DrawItem);
        GetProjectDetails();
       this.preferencesTabControl.SelectedTab= tpCompareUpdate;

    }
```

Comment: can you post more of your code?

Comment: Where are you executing this code? Are you doing it during the Forms constructor or during the OnLoad event? Has InitialiseComponents() been run yet? If you're running this during the constructor before that, then you would definitely get that exception

Comment: its been done during onload event

Comment: I tried to set the tab page in my actual project the way you did and it is working fine. Do you create your tpCompareUpdate tabPage programmaticaly or via the designer?